# Easy Riddle: What A Foolish Goal!

Tags: riddle

> I want love for my enemy
>   But not for myself.
>   I send objects to my enemy,
>   But I don't want my enemy to get them.
>   I am matched with my enemy.
>   But in the end I want the match myself.
>   Why do we run around doing this pointless exercise?

Comment: I wonder if this question will attract a lot of racket.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This riddle points to:

> **Tennis**

I want love for my enemy
But not for myself.

> Love means a score of 0 in tennis, which you would want for your opponent, but not for yourself.

I send objects to my enemy,
But I don't want my enemy to get them.

> You hit balls toward your opponent but you don't want your opponent to reach and return the balls.

I am matched with my enemy.
But in the end I want the match myself.

> Tennis is played in tennis matches, which you want to win instead of the opponent.

Why do we run around doing this pointless exercise?

> Tennis involves lots of running around.  The scoring system is based on games/sets/match instead of points as in other sports.

Answer (score 1):

The other alternative for JSI answer is

> Badminton